# Xml Deserialize exception

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying simply to deserialize a xml file into a class.

This is my xml file:

```
<DirectoryListener inputDirectory="C:\test\" 
                   outputDirectory="C:\keyValueXml\" 
                   fileExt=".xml"/>
```

And this is my class (generated by "Paste Special"):

```
public class DirectoryListenConfig
{
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class DirectoryListener
    {
        private string inputDirectoryField;
        private string outputDirectoryField;
        private string fileExtField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string inputDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return this.inputDirectoryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.inputDirectoryField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string outputDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return this.outputDirectoryField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.outputDirectoryField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string fileExt
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fileExtField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fileExtField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I tried to deserialize the xml file:

```
string path = "DirectoryConfig.xml";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DirectoryListener));

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
directoryConfig = (DirectoryListener)serializer.Deserialize(reader);//Throw an exception
```

And got an exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).).

What is the problem? :\

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DirectoryListener));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            DirectoryListener directoryListener = (DirectoryListener)serializer.Deserialize(reader);//Throw an exception
        }
    }


    [XmlRoot("DirectoryListener")]
    public partial class DirectoryListener
    {
        private string inputDirectoryField;
        private string outputDirectoryField;
        private string fileExtField;

        [XmlAttribute("inputDirectory")]
        public string inputDirectory {get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("outputDirectory")]
        public string outputDirectory { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("fileExt")]
        public string fileExt { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: I tested with above code and didn't get exception.  what is the exception?

Comment: same error (An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).)

Comment: The xml file has an error, not the code.  The xml you posted is correct.